# Print connected components of a graph in python

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to print the connected components of graph. But its printing an object of generator.

This is my graph.py

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import math
import csv
#import random as rand
import sys

def buildG(G, file_, delimiter_):
    #construct the weighted version of the contact graph from cgraph.dat file
    reader = csv.reader(open(file_), delimiter=delimiter_)
    for line in reader:
        if float(line[2]) != 0.0:
            G.add_edge(int(line[0]),int(line[1]),weight=float(line[2]))

def main():
    graph_fn="tempset3.txt";
    G = nx.Graph()  #let's create the graph first
    buildG(G, graph_fn, ',')

    print G.nodes()
    print G.number_of_nodes()

    #nx.draw(G)
    #plt.show(G)

    n = G.number_of_nodes()
    print ("no of nodes: ", n)
    comps=nx.connected_components(G)
    print comps

main()
```

This is my tempset3.txt

```
0,1,9
1,3,5
1,4,17824
2,5,1199
2,6,729
5,7,619
5,8,241
5,10,227
7,8,4
```

When i run it, it gives:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
10
('no of nodes: ', 10)
<generator object connected_components at 0x360f140>
```

How to print connected components properly???

The output should be: **[[0, 1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]]**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `list` on the `generator` object `print (list(comps))`

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
10
no of nodes:  10
[[0, 1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]]
```

Or iterate over the generator object:

```
for comp in comps:
        print (comp)
[0, 1, 3, 4]
[2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
```